# How to reprompt user to put a valid input when user inputs a String (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, input, double

The program should give the output "`Invalid Input`" when the user inputs a string (eg. "`thirty`"), then prompt the user to type a valid input. When I type a string, I get the error message `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException` when inputting a string.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double wallHeight = 0.0;

    boolean valid = true;

    // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
    // Prompt user to input wall's height
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
        wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
        valid = true;
        if (wallHeight <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            valid = false;
        }
     } while (!valid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `Scanner.nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()):

> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range

This means that if the user types in non-numeric characters, `nextDouble()` will throw this exception.

To allow your program to continue, you need to catch the exception and print out an error message. You can do this with a `try...catch` statement. I won't get into the details here since there are a lot of resources already available about how to do this.

Alternatively, you can use [`Scanner.hasNextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()) to check for a double value first.

The links I gave are all from [the official Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html) from Oracle. I strongly encourage you to familiarize yourself with these docs. They explain all of the detail you need for each standard Java class.

Comment: Add try catch that should work try{   //code in here with do while}  catch (Exception e) { sout(e);}

Comment: @KostandinVllahu Or in this case, it is probably better to print out a custom error message rather than the exception.